# DS18B20 device not showing

Tags: driver, wiring, ds18b20

Things I've tried:

- Replacing the DS18B20 twice (First one was a different brand than the other 2)
- Using:

```
modprobe -r -a w1 w1-therm
modprobe w1 pullup=1
modprobe w1-therm strong_pullup=1
```

- Checking `dmesg` (nothing pertaining to w1 or w1-therm)
- Using the multimeter to ensure everything is connected
- Using the multimeter to ensure 3.3v is actually being produced
- Trying a 3.9k ohm resistor instead of 4.7k (per suggestion from blog article)

My `/boot/config.txt` had the following currently: `dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2127,w1-gpio,gpiopin=4`

I added the `gpiopin=4` because it solved it for some people.

`/sys/bus/w1/devices` is still empty. Not even ghost/bug entries. Completely empty.

*Wiring overview*
[image: wiring overview]

*Breadboard wiring*
[image: breadboard wiring]

*Pi wiring*
[image: pi wiring]

Comment: I take it you added `dtoverlay=w1–gpio` in config.txt?

Comment: I see there are some tutorials regarding DS18B20 on a pi that either miss this important step, or seem to think editing config.txt doesn't require a reboot - fortunately the majority of tutorials are not written by cowboys, and do mention the `dtoverlay` step

Comment: Yes I did, and I rebooted several times since I added it.

Comment: cool - didn't see any mention of that step, so wanted to check

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot to add that. I'll go ahead and my dtoverlay line to the original post.

Comment: You only need the w1-gpio dtoverlay. Remove the 2 modprobes (w1-gpio and w1-therm) and try again.

Comment: @Dirk I've updated my post to explain that. It was a suggestion to add the args to the module loading. I didn't know how to do that via dtoverlay so I unloaded them and inserted them with the pullup args.

Comment: I can't see the DS sensor on the wiring pictures, can you also add picture of it.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right pins? https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin7_gpio4

Comment: The dtoverlay line is incorrect change it to ```dtoverlay=w1-gpio``` on one line and
```dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2127``` on a seperate line.

Comment: @Bungee75 Yellow is DATA, red is VCC, and black is GND.

Comment: @Dougie Yes, I'm using physical pin 7/BCM pin 4. I will try separating those modules when I get home. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dougie that worked perfectly. Thank you so much. If you'll add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your merged dtoverlay line is incorrect. Change it to

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2127
```

reboot and it will work.